# Flutter release apk isn't connecting to the my backend

Tags: flutter, apk

My application is connecting to the my backend in debug mode without any problem. But when i try to get apk release and installed it, network not working. I tried to add  **< uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>** to the **"android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml"** but it doesn't work.

I am taking release apk like this:

```
flutter clean
flutter build apk --release
```

Here is my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.gucarsoft.yemek_tarifi_odev_mobil">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:label="yemek_tarifi_odev_mobil"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
             the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
             while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
             to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
        <meta-data
          android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
          android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
          />
        <!-- Displays an Android View that continues showing the launch screen
             Drawable until Flutter paints its first frame, then this splash
             screen fades out. A splash screen is useful to avoid any visual
             gap between the end of Android's launch screen and the painting of
             Flutter's first frame. -->
        <meta-data
          android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
          android:resource="@drawable/launch_background"
          />
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
         This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="flutterEmbedding"
        android:value="2" />
</application>
```

And it's my example request:

```
static Future<UserModel> register(String username, String password) async {
try {
  String token;

  final response = await http.post(
    url + "/register",
    headers: <String, String>{
      'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
    },
    body: jsonEncode(<String, String>{
      'username': username,
      'password': password,
      'email': username,
    }),
  ); //headers: header);
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    return new UserModel();
  } else {
    print("error!");
    return null;
  }
} catch (e) {
  print("error!\n" + e.toString());
  return null;
}
```

}

Comment: There’s nothing wrong with the commands, can you provide some code from where you’re trying to connect?

Comment: static Future<UserModel> register( ....bla bla) async {
    try {
      final response = await http.post(
        url + "/register",
        headers: bla..bla...
        body: jsonEncode(<String, String>{
          'username': username,
          'password': password,
        }),
      ); 
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        return new UserModel();
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    } catch (e) {
      return null;
    }
  }

Comment: it's working but only in debug mode

Comment: Comments have a 600 character limit. Could you edit the question to include the code without the headers removed? Also include the full AndroidManifest.

Comment: @JediBurrell thank you, i edited my question.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to put this config in your project:

Create a file in `res/xml` folder, for exemplo `network_security_config.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <!--Set application-wide security config using base-config tag.-->
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true"/>
</network-security-config>
```

In you AndroidManifest, put this:

```
<application
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
```